# Is there a way to delete a specific grid element in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning tkinter for a school project and I have been playing around with the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def solver(master, e1):

    ax= e1.get()


    if ax !='':
        
        label = tk.Label(master, text= round(float(ax)**0.5,4))
        label.grid(row=0, column=3)
        

def main():


    master = tk.Tk()
    tk.Label(master, text="ax").grid(row=0)


    e1 = tk.Entry(master)


    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


    button1 = tk.Button(master, text='Start', command=lambda : solver(master, e1))
    
    button1.grid(row=12, column= 1)
    
    master.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The program works fine and prints out the square root of the number after pressing "Start", but whenever I input a new number and press the button again it prints the new value over the old one. Is there a way to clear the grid element before printing to it, without creating a separate "clear" button?

I have checked online and haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the grid item, the more common solution is to update the existing item. That means moving the creation outside of the function, and using `configure` to change the value.

Start by creating the result label just like you do the entry:

```
e1 = tk.Entry(master)
result = tk.Label(master, text="", width=10)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
result.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Next, pass the result label to your function:

```
button1 = tk.Button(master, text='Start', command=lambda : solver(master, e1, result))
```

And finally, modify your function to update the result label rather than creating a new result label:

```
def solver(master, e1, result):
    ax = e1.get()
    if ax !='':
        value = float(ax)**0.5,4
        result.configure(text=value)
```